# Simple Cogenerator for the category of left $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

> I want to prove that if the category of left $R$-modules has a simple cogenerator $M$, then $R$ is a simple ring. (Here, $R$ is an arbitrary ring with $1$.)

My try is to take an ideal $I$ of $R$ and consider $IM$ which is a submodule of $M$. Since $M$ is simple, so $IM=0$ or $IM=M$. But, $M$ is a cogenerator, so it is faithful. Hence, the former case leads to $I=0$. For the latter case $IM=M$ I am stuck and appreciate anybody helping me. Also, I am aware of the well-known fact that $M$ is a cogenerator if and only if the injective hull of every simple left $R$-module is isomorphic to a direct summand of $M$. Applying this to the simple $M$, one infers that $M$ could be an injective $R$-module. Then...!

Comment: Hint: If $IM=M$, consider what left $R$-module homomorphisms there are from $R/I$ to $M$.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: Since $M$ is a cogenerator, there is an injection $F$ from $R/I$ to a direct product of $M_i$ with all $M_i=M$ by an indexing set. Each component of $F$ is an $R$-homomorphism from $R/I$ to $M$. So, if all such components are the zero homomorphisms then the kernel of $F$ would be zero, i.e. $I=R$. But, otherwise, there is a nonzero component $F_i$. By simplicity of $M$ the map $F_i$ is onto. Now,...?

Comment: Sorry, it would have been more helpful to suggest considering homomorphisms from both $I$ and $R/I$ to $M$. Since $M$ is injective, the s.e.s. $$0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$$ induces a s.e.s. $$0\to\operatorname{Hom}(R/I,M)\to\operatorname{Hom}(R,M)\to\operatorname{Hom}(I,M)\to 0$$ of left $R$-modules. But $\operatorname{Hom}(R,M)\cong M$, and $M$ is simple ...

Comment: All right! Since $M$ is simple and the latter sequence is exact, so one of $\operatorname{Hom} (R/I,M)$ or $\operatorname{Hom} (I,M)$ is zero. Now, I could argue as above, once for the case of  $\operatorname{Hom} (R/I,M)$ being zero, and once again for the other case, the former gives $R=I$, and the latter gives $I=0$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.